# Aerogear UnifiedPush Server error at notification send: "DeprecatedEndpoint"

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, aerogear

I'm using FCM Push Notifications with AeroGear's UnifiedPush Server 1.2 for sending notification to my android application. I have created an application in firebase and I am using it with aerogear.

After building the app (with cordova) and everything my device was successfully shown in 'device' tab (I am using aerogear-cordova-push#3.0.1). But when I want to send a notification I am getting the next **error:**

> Variant Test has failed: Error sending payload to FCM server: HTTP Status Code: 400(Error=DeprecatedEndpoint)

Did anyone encountered the same problem?

The notifications worked until now and I have created this new variant just for debugging purposes. I have another one configured for iOS and doesn't have any problems.
Tell me if I should provide more details.

```js
    var pushConfig = {
        pushServerURL: "http://aerogear.test.com/ag-push/",
        android: {
           "senderID": "32132",
           "variantID": "fag3-3rf",
           "variantSecret": "ff44-sdvs"
        },
        ios: {
            variantID: "bgfsbs",
            variantSecret: "fdgd"
        },
        categories: subscriptions
    };
```

Comment: Can you add which version of UnifiedPush Server are you using?

Comment: This is caused by using an older version of UPS.  A few years ago we moved to the new endpoints; you should be able to upgrade without much "trouble".

A small caveat, we've also started distributing UPS as a docker formatted container instead of just a war file.  You can use environment variables to configure the container to talk to your old database for a more seamless upgrade.  If you're using a truly ancient version you might need to migrate your database schema using the migration scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have added the version to my post and performed an upgrade to 2.4.0. The notifications are successfully processed (Payload submitted to 3rd party push network for further processing), with the deprecation error gone. But I still don't get the notifications on my phone.